# AngularJS material loading bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to integrate https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear
when a new view is loading.

SO the question how to get the value of current page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the percent loaded that the page is?

I think most page loaders just make up a percent/amount of time for the bar because you can't get a percent of a single file that is loaded.

If you know you are loading, 3 files of 10kb, 20kb, and 30kb.  Then, you could check when each file loads and compute a percentage from that.  (That is probably how sites like gmail compute a percentage.)

In summary, it's probably best to use the indeterminate bar and a variable in your controller for if the page has loaded ($scope.loaded) that is either true or false.  Then, use ng-hide="loaded".